# Validation xpages file download control

Tags: file, validation, xpages

I have to do a validation in component file download Control, checking if any file is listed. Does anyone know how to do this validating. How can I get the object representing the xpages component and list the files by any of its methods?

Comment: Could you please provide more information about where and when exactly do you want to check the existence of any file? What do you want to do if there are no files to download?

Comment: I mean the use case, to say shortly...

Answer (score 0):

here is some code I use to get hold on the upload via ssjs (if you want that)

```
var con = facesContext.getExternalContext();
var request:com.sun.faces.context.MyHttpServletRequestWrapper = con.getRequest();
var fileDataName = getClientId('ctrlUpload') ;
var map:java.util.Map = request.getParameterMap();      
var fileData:com.ibm.xsp.http.UploadedFile = map.get(fileDataName);
if( fileData == null ){
    growl.createGrowlMessage("<strong>Warning</strong> no file to upload selected","danger");
    return;
}

var tempClientFile = fileData.getClientFileName();
var tempFile:java.io.File = fileData.getServerFile();
var filePath = tempFile.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath();
var correctedFile = new java.io.File(filePath+java.io.File.separator + tempClientFile ); 
var success = tempFile.renameTo(correctedFile);

var doc:NotesDocument = attachDoc.getDocument(true);        
var rtFiles:NotesRichTextItem = null;

if(!(doc.hasItem("Files"))){            
    rtFiles = doc.createRichTextItem("Files");
}else{          
    rtFiles = doc.getFirstItem("Files");
}

rtFiles.embedObject(lotus.domino.local.EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT,"",correctedFile.getAbsolutePath(), null); 
correctedFile.renameTo(tempFile);
```

attachDoc is the reference to the data-binding I have set up:

```
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument formName="fa_Attachment"
        var="attachDoc">
    </xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>
```

Comment: But the code you indicated would be to handle a validation of the upload control and not the download control, correct? I need a validation for the download control.

Comment: oops sorry my mistake